# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Install Failure

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, usb-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a small laptop previously successfully, however after a recent upgrade attempt (to 18.04?), it would no longer run.  I have now attempted multiple times to reinstall ubuntu 16.04 LTS from the same USB drive I originally installed it, however now when the install finishes, I don't get any prompt to remove the USB device at the end of installation.  I have tried to remove the USB stick as it restarts, however this fails to start ubuntu properly, as does shutting down after rebooting and being prompted to try or install ubuntu.

It does start with the video screen being badly distorted so only a portion of the right hand side of the screen is visible.  Multiple restarts fail to load ubuntu correctly, with the same video screen distortion, and now I am on my fifth or sixth installation attempt, varying one thing or another hoping I will stumble onto a successful combination of factors to get it installed and bootable.

I don't know what else to try at this point beside deleting the contents of the usb stick with ubuntu installation on it, and recreate an installation USB stick again.  As I said however, the past successful installation of ubuntu from this usb stick is making me think the problem is elsewhere.

If anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: when you boot from USB and reach prompt to either try or install does it boot properly when you choose try ?

Comment: I haven't tried this.  I am in the middle of yet another install attempt.  I did want to mention that with the installation the video screen displays correctly.  If this install is not successful, I will select try and report the results.